# Apache Camel 3.8.0 Not Reading Files From XML-DSL Routes

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, file-processing

I just have written one application using Java 11 (open-jdk 11.0.2), Spring framework 5.3.23, And Apache Camel 3.8.0; which is supposed to read an incoming file and do process it.
For this I have written XML-DSL which defines the routes in it. I'm sharing part of it. The problem is the camel is not reading the file at all and no **camelLock** file is being created on incoming file. Can anyone help me in this issue to resolve this ?

### XML-DSL : actionRoutes.xml -`

```
<beans  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.8.0.xsd">

<!-- Only the routeContext is here -->
<routeContext id="actionRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <!-- INWARD/OUTWARD RETURN route defined - Set 01 -->
    <route id="route14">
        <from uri="file:E:\\ICICI\\reports?delete=true&amp;filter=#checkBankStatus" />
        <log message="INWARD / OUTWARD RETURN PROCESS : [${body}]" />

        <doTry>
            <process ref="inwardProcessorICI" />
            <doCatch>
                <!-- catch multiple exceptions -->
                <exception>java.io.IOException</exception>
                <exception>java.lang.IllegalStateException</exception>
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>
    </route>
```

`

The **pom.xml** has enlisted the required dependencies for Spring framework 5.3.23 and **Apache camel 3.8.0** -

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core-osgi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-ftp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-http -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-spring-integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-integration</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks in advance.

Jayanta Pramanik